WebSocket not being triggered from outside its class
I am using a Spring Backend with a Angular+Ionic frontend. I have created a WebSocket to trigger my frontend when a Teacher modifies a Grade in Moodle. This is irrelevant, just to give you some context.
So the problem is that mi fronted is correctly subscribed:
constructor(private apiUserService: ApiUserService) { 
this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/newGrade');
this.webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event.data)
}}

And it gets the first message correctly. The problem is that when I update my DB and calls the Handler to be triggered it doesn't respond. I know that the method and my plugin in Moodle is working because the DB is UPDATED:
@Autowired
private NewGradeHandler newGradeHandler; 

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@PostMapping("/updateGrade")
public ResponseEntity<String> miEndpoint(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> datos) throws Exception {
    try {
        // Obtener los datos de la solicitud
        Long userId = Long.parseLong(datos.get("userid").toString());
        if (userId != -1) {
            Long courseId = Long.parseLong(datos.get("courseid").toString());
            int mark = Integer.parseInt(datos.get("grade").toString());
            String assignmentName = datos.get("assignmentname").toString();

            // Buscar el usuario y la asignatura
            User student = userService.findById(userId);
            Subject subject = subjectService.getSubject(courseId);

            // Crear una nueva nota o actualizarla si existe
            if (!subjectMarkService.existsByStudentIdAndSubjectIdAndNameMark(student, subject, assignmentName)) {
                Subject_Mark newMark = new Subject_Mark(student, subject, mark, "Ordinaria", assignmentName); 
                subjectMarkService.save(newMark);
                Subject_Mark updatedGrade = subjectMarkService.getLastSubjectMarkAdded();
                sendMessageToWebSocket(updatedGrade);
            } else {
                updateExistingMark(student, subject, mark, assignmentName);
            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok("Nota creada/actualizada correctamente");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error al convertir los datos");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void updateExistingMark(User student, Subject subject, int mark, String assignmentName) throws Exception {
    Subject_Mark existingMark = subjectMarkService.findByStudentIdAndSubjectIdAndNameMark(student, subject, assignmentName).get();
    existingMark.setMark(mark);
    subjectMarkService.save(existingMark);
}

private void sendMessageToWebSocket(Subject_Mark grade) throws Exception {
TextMessage message = new TextMessage(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(grade));
for (WebSocketSession session : newGradeHandler.getSessions()) {
    session.sendMessage(message);
}

}
My handler and its config is:
@Configuration@EnableWebSocketpublic class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new NewGradeHandler(), "/newGrade").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler NewGradeHandler() {
    return new NewGradeHandler(); 
}}

And this is my Handler:
@Componentpublic class NewGradeHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
private final List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
@Autowired
private SubjectMarkService subjectMarkService;

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {

    Subject_Mark newGrade = subjectMarkService.getLastSubjectMarkAdded();
    
        TextMessage message = new TextMessage(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(newGrade));
        session.sendMessage(message);
    sessions.add(session);
}

public List<WebSocketSession> getSessions() {
    return sessions;
}}

I have searched some guides but the update the wbesocket from inside the class which I know it works: https://medium.com/@parthiban.rajalingam/introduction-to-web-sockets-using-spring-boot-and-angular-b11e7363f051
I would appreciate some help.

I discovered that using:
@Autowired
private NewGradeHandler newGradeHandler; 

I was creating a new instance without the previous connections. So, if this happens to you. in the method you want to consume your WebSocket do:

declare:
 @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext applicationContext; // Inyecta el ApplicationContext


Use this instance, make sure the String in the getBean method has the sam name as your class:


NewGradeHandler newGradeHandler = applicationContext.getBean("NewGradeHandler",NewGradeHandler.class);
